# Find the Probability??

Tags: probability

A deck of playing cards contains 52 cards. What is the probability of pulling out a King of Diamonds and without replacing it, then an ace of spades?

1/52 x 1/51 = 1/ 2652

My thought process is that there is one king diamond card so you take it out (1/52). then you have to pull one ace of spades being 1/51.

Comment: Hi Christian, could you please include your attempt in the post? Any attempt is ok, then people can help where you are stuck

Comment: i included my math. I just dont know if im right

Comment: Please also include why you think you have to multiply $1/52$ by $1/51$. In other words, include your thought process.

Answer (score 2):

Prob. of pulling out a King of Diamonds = n(King of Diamonds)/n(Cards in the deck) = 1/52

Now, due to no replacement, the prob. of pulling out an Ace of Spades = n(Ace of Spades)/n(Cards in the deck - 1) = 1/51

So final probability = (1/52)(1/51) = 1/2652.
Note: We're multiplying because of the use of "and". Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much! Now i think i understand it more.